# How to find and total all "numbers" associated with a given name in a single text string?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google spreadsheet cell the contains multiple text entries, each followed by with a digit number.  The single cell content looks like this (alt+enter forces them to display in "rows):

NameOne 5
NameTwo 2
NameThree 2
NameOne 4
NameTwo 1

I want to pass to the Function a name (ex NameOne) and the Cell address of interest (ex A1) and have the function return the sum of a numbers associated with NameOne (ex = 9) or NameTwo (ex = 3).

If there is no match, I would like the function to return "blank".

I would appreciate it if someone with could help me with this.

Comment: Please show what you have done till now. How your current script looks like. This way we can know you have put some effort in doing this task.

Answer (score 0):

Following approach would work

1. first get the content of the "single string cell" stored in a string
2. split the string between the numerals
3. check for string equality

```js
var content = "NameOne 5 NameTwo 2 NameThree 2 NameOne 4 NameTwo 1"

var content_splitted = content.split(/(\d+)/)

function get_sum(name) {
var sum =0
for (i = 0; i < content_splitted.length; i++) {

  if (content_splitted[i].trim() === name) {

    sum = sum + Number(content_splitted[i + 1])
  }
}

if (sum > 0) {
console.log(sum)
}

}
get_sum("NameOne")
get_sum("NameTwo")
get_sum("NameSeven")
```